# What is the proper data structure to store self-sorting list with repeating keys?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

I need something that will work in O(log(n)) complexity, and I thought about AVL trees, but the problem is that some keys may repeat themselves (score of a person for example), so I can't think of how to implement it as a tree. What is a proper way to do this?

Comment: Do you just need to store some data along with the key? [These notes](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/9.BST.html) on binary search trees (not AVL) might help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options available. Most flavors of binary search trees can easily be modified to allow for nodes with duplicated values, since the balancing operations (usually) purely consist of rotations, which keep the sequence in order. For cases like these, you'd just do a normal BST insertion, but every time you see a duplicated value, you just arbitrarily move to the left or the right and continue as if the value were distinct.

Skiplists are particularly easy to update to support multiple copies of each key, since they don't do any complicated structural updates on insertions or deletions.

If you don't have auxiliary information associated with each key, then another simpler option would be to store a standard binary search tree, but to augment each node with a "count" field indicating how many logical copies of that field exist. Every time you do an insertion, if the key doesn't exist, you create it with count 1. If it already exists, you just increment the count in the existing node. Deletions would be implemented analogously.

Of course, if you don't want to roll your own data structure, just go and find a good implementation of a multimap or multiset, which should get the job done for you quite nicely. Depending on your Programming Language of Choice, you might even find these in the standard libraries. :-)